# Not able launch multiple edge browser/instance in Selenium? Selenium allows only single instance for edge?

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge

Not able to launch multiple edge browser in selenium. I want to open second instance once I have done actions required in first application and cross check the same in another application without closing the first instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known limitation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/17754737/) of the driver for EdgeHTML-based versions of Microsoft Edge. It is not a problem with Selenium *per se*, but one with the driver, which is created an maintained by Microsoft. Criticism, complaints, and bug reports should be directed there. Having said that, note that the driver for Chromium-based Edge, [now in beta](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/), do not have this limitation.

Answer (score -1):

This is a [known issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/17754737/), at the moment you can only run 1 instance of Microsoft Edge. That is a limitation of MicrosoftWebDriver. You could feedback this issue at the bottom of [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver) and [create a pull request on github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/edge-developer/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%224859f651-74ee-4bbb-33c7-d999d4933070%22&in=body) about this issue.